# Is it possible to make a python script that runs on a specific terminal-profile

Tags: command-line, bash, python, .sh

I have this python script that connects my desktop to the internet. there is not much text in it only a few messages about current status and time. So it would be really nice if i can open it (.sh file that opens the .py file) in a terminal that has a particular profile (with short frame size and dark background etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put following script at the end of `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ x$DISPLAY != x ] ; then
    gnome-terminal --save-config=/tmp/prof
    PROFILE=$(grep 'ProfileID=' /tmp/prof | sed 's/ProfileID=//g' | tail -1)
    if [ "$PROFILE" == "Profile1" ] ; then
        # run your script here
    fi
fi
```

First `if` statement checks if you are running GNOME terminal, not a virtual console one. Then configuration of profile is saved into `/tmp/prof`. Third line reads profile name from that file. Inner `if` statement checks if it's a profile in which you want to call your script.

To list names of your profiles run:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/global/profile_list
[Default,Profile0,Profile1]
```

Comment: It worked! yay. Thankyou for the well written answer.